# Cycles Subsurface Modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am following this [Blender Guru tutorial for micro-displacements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRzzaRvVDng&t=1268s)

I follow every step. However, when I apply the Subdivision Modifier, the geometry does not change.  The plane remains flat, whereas the geometry displaces in the tutorial.

This happens whether I use Supported or Experimental features.

I am using Blender 2.79

Does anyone have an idea what would prevent the geometry from displacing?

Thank you,

Nathan

Comment: It is hard to find out what's wrong with so little information. Could you upload your give a link to your .blend file? (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is a good website to use for stackexchange)

Comment: yeah or maybe post a picture so we can see what is going on

Comment: Did you remember to tab twice to recalculate?

Comment: Based on what you have said I'm thinking maybe you didn't turn up the "View" number that adds more geometry.

Comment: "I follow every step. However, when I apply the Subdivision Modifier, the geometry does not change." -  Applying means you hit the Apply button after adding the modifier this way transferring its effects permanently to the mesh. You should not apply the modifier, you should just add it. If you meant you only add it, mind the terminology, please, because you are saying a completely different thing.